# Error while adding spring security dependency in spring template mvc project in STS

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm starting to learn spring framework. I'm using Springsource Toolsuite Version:3.1.0.RELEASE) as my IDE. My spring version is 3. It has the option to create new Spring Mvc template project. I've created it just by clicking and found a nice up and running mvc project.

However, I'm facing some issues while adding spring security dependency in POM.XML. I've added the following dependencies:

```
spring-security-core; spring-security-web; spring-security-config;
```

All of them are of version 3.1.3 Release.

Then I clean it and update maven dependency. It gets error. Problem is, the type of error is sometimes different. I'm sick of searching for each type of them.

My question is, what am I doing wrong? I don't think adding a few dependencies in POM.XML of a untouched template project should result in this sort of disaster.

Can anyone suggest me something? It would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide (parts of) your POM? What is your IDE?

Comment: I'm using STS(Springsource Toolsuite) as my IDE and my POM is just the default POM of spring mvc project in this IDE. The extra dependency I've added is mentioned in my post.

Comment: Please post the pom (even if it is more or less default), some of us just don't know that pom in detail.

Comment: And please post the exact (last) error message.